Unknown error sending SMS with SimCom SIM7600 module
I need to send SMS message with the SIM7600 module. When I tried some weeks ago, the module was able to send message normally, but from yesterday the module answer with "+CMS ERROR: Unknown error" when I use the "AT+CGMS" command.
The SIM card is registered on the network, because I can receive the SMSs without problems.
To be sure that the SIM card works properly, I tried it with an old GSM module (Quectel M66). With this, I can send SMS normally.
The only thing I noted is the following: when I send message with the Quectel GSM module, the message indication is very high: when I sent the last message, the module answered me “+CMGS:192”.
Therefore, I have tried to put a new SIM card in the SIM7600 module, and I finally managed to send an SMS (in this case, the message indication was lower, “+CMGS:8”, because the SIM is new).
Is it possible that the SIM7600 have problems with SIM cards used previously with other modules and, therefore, with an high number of SMS previously sent? How I can solve this problem?

Could it be that sms storage is full?
